# Why do you need to create a cursor when querying a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, database-cursor

I'm completely new to [Python's sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html) (and SQL in general for that matter), and this just completely stumps me. The abundant lack of descriptions of [`cursor` objects](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects) (rather, their necessity) also seems odd.

This snippet of code is the preferred way of doing things:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''insert into table "users" values ("Jack Bauer", "555-555-5555")''')
conn.commit()
c.close()
```

This one isn't, even though it works just as well and without the (seemingly pointless) `cursor`:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite")
conn.execute('''insert into table "users" values ("Jack Bauer", "555-555-5555")''')
conn.commit()
```

Can anyone tell me why I need a `cursor`?

It just seems like pointless overhead. For every method in my script that accesses a database, I'm supposed to create and destroy a `cursor`?

Why not just use the `connection` object?

Answer (score 94):

Just a misapplied abstraction it seems to me. A db cursor is an abstraction, meant for data set traversal.

From [Wikipedia article on subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29):

> In computer science and technology, a database cursor is a control
>   structure that enables traversal over the records in a database.
>   Cursors facilitate subsequent processing in conjunction with the
>   traversal, such as retrieval, addition and removal of database
>   records. The database cursor characteristic of traversal makes cursors
>   akin to the programming language concept of iterator.

And:

> Cursors can not only be used to fetch data from the DBMS into an
>   application but also to identify a row in a table to be updated or
>   deleted. The SQL:2003 standard defines positioned update and
>   positioned delete SQL statements for that purpose. Such statements do
>   not use a regular WHERE clause with predicates. Instead, a cursor
>   identifies the row. The cursor must be opened and already positioned
>   on a row by means of FETCH statement.

If you check the [docs on Python sqlite module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html), you can see that a python module `cursor` is needed even for a `CREATE TABLE` statement, so it's used for cases where a mere `connection` object should suffice - as correctly pointed out by the OP. Such abstraction is different from what people understand a db cursor to be and hence, the confusion/frustration on the part of users. Regardless of efficiency, it's just a conceptual overhead. Would be nice if it was pointed out in the docs that the python module `cursor` is bit different than what a cursor is in SQL and databases.

Comment: +1 for acknowledging the (at first) very confusing distinction between "traditional" db cursors and the cursors used for a db in Python

Comment: Actually, one can just plainly [create a table even without using a cursor](https://xania.org/200711/python-sqlite-gotcha).

Comment: The use of cursor seems consistent with the definition you provided: "database cursor is a control structure that enables traversal over the records in a database".    For example `c.execute('''SELECT * FROM users''')` returns an iterator that you can call `fetchall()` on (or another cursor method).  Some SQL queries return empty iterators, but that should be expected, not surprising.

Answer (score 67):

According to the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute) `connection.execute()` is a **nonstandard shortcut** that creates an intermediate cursor object:

> Connection.execute
>   This is a nonstandard shortcut that creates a cursor object by calling the cursor() method, calls the cursor’s execute() method with the parameters given, and returns the cursor.

Answer (score 58):

> 12.6.8. Using sqlite3 **efficient**ly
>
> 12.6.8.1. Using **shortcut** methods
>
> Using the **nonstandard** `execute()`, `executemany()` and `executescript()` methods of the Connection object, your code can be written **more concise**ly because you don’t have to create the (often **superfluous**) Cursor objects explicitly. Instead, the Cursor objects are created implicitly and these shortcut methods return the cursor objects. This way, you can execute a SELECT statement and iterate over it directly using only a single call on the Connection object.

([sqlite3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#using-sqlite3-efficiently); emphasis mine.)

> Why not just use the connection object?

Because those methods of the connection object are [nonstandard](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute), i.e. they are not part of [Python Database API Specification v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) (PEP 249).

As long as you use the standard methods of the Cursor object, you can be sure that if you switch to another database implementation that follows the above specification, your code will be fully portable. Perhaps you will only need to change the `import` line.

But if you use the `connection.execute` there is a chance that switching won't be that straightforward. That's the main reason you might want to use `cursor.execute` instead.

However if you are certain that you're not going to switch, I'd say it's completely OK to take the `connection.execute` shortcut and be "efficient".

Comment: Now (Sep-2023) - > Info about connection shortcuts is here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-use-connection-shortcut-methods

Answer (score 52):

You need a cursor object to fetch results. Your example works because it's an `INSERT` and thus you aren't trying to get any rows back from it, but if you look at the [`sqlite3` docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html), you'll notice that there aren't any `.fetchXXXX` methods on connection objects, so if you tried to do a `SELECT` without a cursor, you'd have no way to get the resulting data.

Cursor objects allow you to keep track of which result set is which, since it's possible to run multiple queries before you're done fetching the results of the first.

Comment: Also worth keeping in mind: [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) does not define `execute` on a connection object, this is an `sqlite3` extension.

Comment: It still works with SELECT statements: http://pastebin.com/5ZbhfEn7. The reason being that you aren't calling any .fetchXXXX methods on the connection object, you're calling a .fetchXXXX method on the object returned by the connection's .execute() method.

Comment: @Jack: Right, but you still wind up with a Cursor one way or another.

Comment: Yes. But one way you end up with a (seemingly) unnecessary cursor with which to query the database :p

Comment: If you use the cursor to query, the same cursor is used for the results; you don't wind up with an "extra" cursor.

Comment: Well would you look at that - so it does. You said, "[c]ursor objects allow you to keep track of which result set is which, since it's possible to run multiple queries before you're done fetching the results of the first". I have the database setup to autocommit changes, so it seems like this reason for using cursors is void in my case (unless I misunderstood). Would it still be bad form to avoid using them?

Comment: Explicitly using cursors is a good habit to get into, since there will probably be future projects you work on where things are *not* auto-commit.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. Why using auto-commit void the benefit of the cursor's ability to distinguish different result sets? Even with auto-commit, don't we need to know which result set is which? Even it's too long to answer in the comment, maybe point me to a documentation or example? Thx!

Answer (score 5):

It gives us the ability to have multiple separate working environments through the same connection to the database.