# Why close a cursor for Sqlite3 in Python

Tags: python, sqlite, python-internals, database-cursor, python-db-api

Is there any benefit to closing a cursor when using Python's [sqlite3 module](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#module-sqlite3)?  Or is it just an artifact of the [DB API v2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) that might only do something useful for other databases?

It makes sense that [connection.close()](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.close) releases resources; however, it is unclear what *cursor.close()* actually does, whether it actually releases some resource or does nothing.  The docs for it are unenlightening:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
>>> c = conn.cursor()
>>> help(c.close)
Help on built-in function close:

close(...)
    Closes the cursor.
```

Note, this is a completely different question than [Why do you need to create a cursor when querying a sqlite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318126/why-do-you-need-to-create-a-cursor-when-querying-a-sqlite-database). I know what cursors are for. The question is about what the `cursor.close()` method actually does and whether there is any benefit to calling it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do you need to create a cursor when querying a sqlite database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318126/why-do-you-need-to-create-a-cursor-when-querying-a-sqlite-database)

Comment: @ChristophTerasa This question isn't about cursor creation.  It is about what the *close()* method on cursors actually does and whether there is any benefit to calling it.

Comment: Get one million cursors, close them or not, and compare the memory usage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Analysis

CPython `_sqlite3.Cursor.close` corresponds to `pysqlite_cursor_close` which besides a few sanity checks and marking it as closed, [does this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ad101b3/Modules/_sqlite/cursor.c#L970):

```
if (self->statement) {
    (void)pysqlite_statement_reset(self->statement);
    Py_CLEAR(self->statement);
}
```

[`pysqlite_statement_reset`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3ad101b3/Modules/_sqlite/statement.c#L347) in turn calls [`sqlite3_reset`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/reset.html) from SQLite's C API:

> The sqlite3_reset() function is called to reset a prepared statement object back to its initial state, ready to be re-executed. Any SQL statement variables that had values bound to them using the sqlite3_bind_*() API retain their values. Use sqlite3_clear_bindings() to reset the bindings.
>
> [...]
>
> The sqlite3_reset(S) interface does not change the values of any bindings on the prepared statement S.

[Prepared Statement Object](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) API is used to bind parameters e.g. in  `_sqlite3.Cursor.execute`. So if `sqlite3_clear_bindings` was used, it might have been able to free up some memory used to store the parameters, but I don't see it called anywhere in CPython/pysqlite.

### Experiment

I use [memory-profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) to draw a memory usage chart and produce line-by-line reports.

```
import logging
import sqlite3
import time

# For the function brackets to appear on the chart leave this out:
#
#     If your Python file imports the memory profiler 
#     "from memory_profiler import profile" these timestamps will not be
#     recorded. Comment out the import, leave your functions decorated, 
#     and re-run.
#
# from memory_profiler import profile


class CursorCuriosity:
  
    cursor_num = 20_000
    param_num = 200
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
        self.cursors = []
    
    @profile
    def create(self):
        logging.info('Creating cursors')
        sql = 'SELECT {}'.format(','.join(['?'] * self.param_num))
        for i in range(self.cursor_num):
            params = [i] * self.param_num
            cur = self.conn.execute(sql, params)
            self.cursors.append(cur)
    
    @profile
    def close(self):
        logging.info('Closing cursors')
        for cur in self.cursors:
            cur.close()

    @profile
    def delete(self):
        logging.info('Destructing cursors')
        self.cursors.clear()
    
    @profile    
    def disconnect(self):
        logging.info('Disconnecting')
        self.conn.close()
        del self.conn


@profile
def main():
    curcur = CursorCuriosity()
    
    logging.info('Sleeping before calling create()')
    time.sleep(2)
    curcur.create()
    
    logging.info('Sleeping before calling close()')
    time.sleep(2)
    curcur.close()
    
    logging.info('Sleeping before calling delete()')
    time.sleep(2)
    curcur.delete()
    
    logging.info('Sleeping before calling disconnect()')
    time.sleep(2)
    curcur.disconnect()
    
    logging.info('Sleeping before exit')
    time.sleep(2)  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level='INFO', format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    main()
```

I run it first with the `profile` import commented out to get the plot.

```
mprof run -T 0.05 cursor_overhead.py
mprof plot
```

[image: mprof plot]

Then with the import to get output in the terminal.

```
mprof run -T 0.05 cursor_overhead.py
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    51     19.1 MiB     19.1 MiB           1   @profile
    52                                         def main():
    53     19.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       curcur = CursorCuriosity()
    54                                             
    55     19.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info('Sleeping before calling create()')
    56     19.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       time.sleep(2)
    57   2410.3 MiB   2391.2 MiB           1       curcur.create()
    58                                             
    59   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info('Sleeping before calling close()')
    60   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       time.sleep(2)
    61   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       curcur.close()
    62                                             
    63   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info('Sleeping before calling delete()')
    64   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       time.sleep(2)
    65   1972.2 MiB   -438.1 MiB           1       curcur.delete()
    66                                             
    67   1972.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info('Sleeping before calling disconnect()')
    68   1972.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       time.sleep(2)
    69   1872.7 MiB    -99.5 MiB           1       curcur.disconnect()
    70                                             
    71   1872.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       logging.info('Sleeping before exit')
    72   1872.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       time.sleep(2)
```

And individual method for completeness.

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    24     19.1 MiB     19.1 MiB           1       @profile
    25                                             def create(self):
    26     19.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           logging.info('Creating cursors')
    27     19.1 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           sql = 'SELECT {}'.format(','.join(['?'] * self.param_num))
    28   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       20001           for i in range(self.cursor_num):
    29   2410.1 MiB      0.0 MiB       20000               params = [i] * self.param_num
    30   2410.3 MiB   2374.3 MiB       20000               cur = self.conn.execute(sql, params)
    31   2410.3 MiB     16.9 MiB       20000               self.cursors.append(cur)
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    33   2410.3 MiB   2410.3 MiB           1       @profile
    34                                             def close(self):
    35   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           logging.info('Closing cursors')
    36   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       20001           for cur in self.cursors:
    37   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB       20000               cur.close()
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    39   2410.3 MiB   2410.3 MiB           1       @profile
    40                                             def delete(self):
    41   2410.3 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           logging.info('Destructing cursors')
    42   1972.2 MiB   -438.1 MiB           1           self.cursors.clear()
```

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    44   1972.2 MiB   1972.2 MiB           1       @profile    
    45                                             def disconnect(self):
    46   1972.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           logging.info('Disconnecting')
    47   1972.2 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           self.conn.close()
    48   1872.7 MiB    -99.5 MiB           1           del self.conn
```

### Conclusion

1. Closing a `sqlite3.Cursor` doesn't free up memory (but does a little but of work, manipulating the SQLite prepared statement's state)
2. Deleting/destructing a cursor frees up memory
3. Deleting/destructing a `sqlite3.Connection` frees up memory (closing doesn't)

Comment: That was an incredibly amazing analysis, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the case of SQLite, there isn't much difference but the API for databases is not just for embedded databases but for all SQL databases.

For a DBMS, a cursor often implies a session in the client and sometimes on the server.

So, if you are not using a reference counting implementation of Python (such as CPython), then a lot of resources could be tied up until GC frees them.