# Running sqlite queries in a loop slows down after 20 calls

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I am running a query on and there is a select statement that is working much slower than I thought it would.

I have one db method for getting a single table

```
def get_tables_by_id(self, id)
   with self.conn as conn:
     c = conn.cursor()
     c.execute(SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE foreign_id = ? AND date(date) >= ? AND date(date) <= ?, params)
     return c.fetchall()
```

I then have another method to do this many times under different parameters. Instead of preparing a single statement to fetch them all at once I thought I would just loop and call `get_tables_by_id` because I am not hitting the database over the network and I would have to do some operations to organize everything if I queried them all at once. I thought since sqlite runs on the filesystem it would be fast... but it slows down after 20 or so calls to the above method. (I am trying to call it 1000 times)

If I however execute the following SQL and run it in one big query, it returns all of the results instantly...

```
q = f"SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE foreign_id IN ({','.join('?' * len(foreign_ids)}) AND date(date) >= ? and date(date) <= ?"
```

I would understand if the looping query took longer, on the order of seconds, but I guess it would take 5 minutes to complete at the rate that it was going at. WHat would be the reason for such a slow down like that?

Comment: one query against a 1000 queries - this is obvious

Comment: All IO is slow (reading files, sending/receiving data over the network), querying an sqlite database is essentially a file read

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest then why would it slow down after about 20?

Comment: Query speed: `sqlite` < `mysql` or `postgresql` < `Redis` or `Memcached`

Comment: I would take a look if you posted the code that can be used to reproduce the problem easily. Do you [close the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43927799/1026)?

Comment: @Nickolay I do close the cursor